# Comma separation in a ruby loop?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on creating a adserver using rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2. In the app I have page at localhost:3000/ads/script that generates the javascript to show the ads. Im looking for some help with the loops.

Here is the code for script.html.erb:

```
<% @ad.each do |ad| %>   

  <% if ad.end_date <= Date.today || ad.start_date >= Date.today %> 

  <% else %>

  var advert<%= ad.id %> = ''
  advert<%= ad.id %>+='<img class="ad" alt="<%= ad.title %>" src="http://<%= request.env["HTTP_HOST"] %><%= ad.image.url %>" border="0" height="<%= ad.best_height %>" width="<%= ad.best_width %>" />';
  advert<%= ad.id %>+='</a>';
  advert<%= ad.id %>+=''; 

  <% end %>  
<% end %>    


document.write( <% @ad.each do |ad|%>
                <% if ad.end_date <= Date.today || ad.start_date >= Date.today %>

                <% else %>
                  avert<%= ad.id %>, 
                <% end %>  
             <% end %>);
```

On the second loop I am trying to add dynamic javascript variables to the document.write that are separated with a comma.  like “document.write(advert1, advert2, advert3) but with the current code it puts a comma after every variable and I need there to not be a trailing comma. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Aside from the comma separation issue, everything works but it doesn't seem very dry and it seems like there could be a better way to do the if else statement... this is my first ruby app and any insight to refactoring would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should filter out "current" ads in the controller by calling an appropriate method in your Ad model. That will make your views much cleaner.

Comment: thanks Lars, still fresh to all this. so, what you are saying is to make a method in the Ad model that filters to my date criteria, then in the controller do something like this @ad.some_method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use join:

```
@ad.select{|ad| !(ad.end_date <= Date.today || ad.start_date >= Date.today)}.collect{|ad| "avert#{ad.id}" }.join(",")
```

Comment: This is becoming kind of a general rule for Ruby and pretty much any other modern language: if you write a loop, chances are, you're doing it wrong and there is some higher-order method, higher-level iterator, combinator, helper or something like that you should use instead.

Comment: @Jorg Definitely agreed on that, personally, I'd put the first select in the controller, and the collect in a helper.